# Google Script Help - Stop try if any data is blank

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google script that I use where staff members enter data such as student email address and info on homework into a spreadsheet.  From that data the student is emailed every day at 10:00 if they need to go in for extra help.  It works very well, however every once in a while there is an error when a row is not completely filled out.  It will simply error and stop the process leaving any students on the sheet under that incomplete entry without an email for the day.  I'm trying to put in an error catch that will notice a cell is blank and pass that row over moving on to the next and not simply stopping.

Here's the jist of that I have now.  Can someone point me in the right direction? I'm not a great programmer by any means.

```
var mainSheet = ivList[i];  
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(mainSheet);


//empty row checker. Ends with lastFullRow
var range = sheet.getDataRange();
var values = range.getValues();
var row = 0;
for (var row=0; row<values.length; row++) {
  if (!values[row].join("")) break;
}
var lastFullRow = row;
//Stop empty row Check

var cell = sheet.getRange(3, 1, lastFullRow, 7);
Logger.log(lastFullRow);

var UserData = cell.getValues();
  try{
    for (var j in UserData) {
      var row = UserData[j];
      var grade = row[0];
      var lastName = row[1];
      var firstName = row[2];
      var studentEmail = row[3];
      var staffEmail= row[4];
      var iCanStatement = row[5];
      var date = row[6];


      // if IV sheet send IV email
     if (i == 0 || i == 2) {
       var emailSubject = "INTERVENTION NOTICE for "+date;
       var studentBody = "NOTICE: This is an automated message confirming that you have been assigned to the INTERVENTION LIST."+"\n"+"\n"+"DATE: "+date+"\n"+"\n"+"FIRST NAME: "+firstName+"\n"+"\n"+"LAST NAME: "+lastName+"\n"+"\n"+"EMAIL ADDRESS: "+studentEmail+"\n"+"\n"+"STAFF MEMBER: "+staffEmail+"\n"+"\n"+"I CAN STATEMENT: "+iCanStatement;
       var staffBody = "NOTICE: This is an automated message confirming that you have assigned a student to the INTERVENTION LIST"+"\n"+"\n"+"DATE: "+date+"\n"+"\n"+"FIRST NAME: "+firstName+"\n"+"\n"+"LAST NAME: "+lastName+"\n"+"\n"+"EMAIL ADDRESS: "+studentEmail+"\n"+"\n"+"STAFF MEMBER: "+staffEmail+"\n"+"\n"+"I CAN STATEMENT: "+iCanStatement;
       var fromName = "**"
     } 

     // if homework sheet send homework Email
     if (i == 1 || i ==3) {
        var emailSubject = "HOMEWORK ROOM NOTICE for "+date;
        var studentBody = "NOTICE: This is an automated message confirming that you have been assigned to the HOMEWORK LIST."+"\n"+"\n"+"DATE: "+date+"\n"+"\n"+"FIRST NAME: "+firstName+"\n"+"\n"+"LAST NAME: "+lastName+"\n"+"\n"+"EMAIL ADDRESS: "+studentEmail+"\n"+"\n"+"STAFF MEMBER: "+staffEmail+"\n"+"\n"+"ASSIGNMENT: "+iCanStatement;
        var staffBody = "NOTICE: This is an automated message confirming that you have assigned a student to the HOMEWORK LIST"+"\n"+"\n"+"DATE: "+date+"\n"+"\n"+"FIRST NAME: "+firstName+"\n"+"\n"+"LAST NAME: "+lastName+"\n"+"\n"+"EMAIL ADDRESS: "+studentEmail+"\n"+"\n"+"STAFF MEMBER: "+staffEmail+"\n"+"\n"+"ASSIGNMENT: "+iCanStatement;
        var fromName = "**"
     }

     // Send Emails
        MailApp.sendEmail(studentEmail, emailSubject, studentBody, {bcc:"**@**.org", name:fromName, replyTo:staffEmail});
        MailApp.sendEmail(staffEmail, emailSubject, staffBody, {name:fromName, replyTo:staffEmail});
      }
  }

  catch(e) {
   MailApp.sendEmail("**@**.org", "Error on Intervention Spreadsheet 3.0", e.message);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is in your lines that calculate the number of rows to process:

```
for (var row=0; row<values.length; row++) {
  if (!values[row].join("")) break;
}
var cell = sheet.getRange(3, 1, lastFullRow, 7);
```

with that, the script would only process the first filled rows. consider using getLastRow instead and moving the check for filled row into the later for loop:

```
var mainSheet = ivList[i];  
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(mainSheet);

var range = sheet.getDataRange();
var values = range.getValues();


var UserData = values;
  try{
    for (var j in UserData) {
      var row = UserData[j];
      // do nothign if the row is empty
      // Updates
      if (!row.join("")) continue;

      // proceed with non empty rows
      var grade = row[0];
      var lastName = row[1];
      var firstName = row[2];
      var studentEmail = row[3];
      var staffEmail= row[4];
      var iCanStatement = row[5];
      var date = row[6];


      // if IV sheet send IV email
     if (i == 0 || i == 2) {
       var emailSubject = "INTERVENTION NOTICE for "+date;
       var studentBody = "NOTICE: This is an automated message confirming that you have been assigned to the INTERVENTION LIST."+"\n"+"\n"+"DATE: "+date+"\n"+"\n"+"FIRST NAME: "+firstName+"\n"+"\n"+"LAST NAME: "+lastName+"\n"+"\n"+"EMAIL ADDRESS: "+studentEmail+"\n"+"\n"+"STAFF MEMBER: "+staffEmail+"\n"+"\n"+"I CAN STATEMENT: "+iCanStatement;
       var staffBody = "NOTICE: This is an automated message confirming that you have assigned a student to the INTERVENTION LIST"+"\n"+"\n"+"DATE: "+date+"\n"+"\n"+"FIRST NAME: "+firstName+"\n"+"\n"+"LAST NAME: "+lastName+"\n"+"\n"+"EMAIL ADDRESS: "+studentEmail+"\n"+"\n"+"STAFF MEMBER: "+staffEmail+"\n"+"\n"+"I CAN STATEMENT: "+iCanStatement;
       var fromName = "**"
     } 

     // if homework sheet send homework Email
     if (i == 1 || i ==3) {
        var emailSubject = "HOMEWORK ROOM NOTICE for "+date;
        var studentBody = "NOTICE: This is an automated message confirming that you have been assigned to the HOMEWORK LIST."+"\n"+"\n"+"DATE: "+date+"\n"+"\n"+"FIRST NAME: "+firstName+"\n"+"\n"+"LAST NAME: "+lastName+"\n"+"\n"+"EMAIL ADDRESS: "+studentEmail+"\n"+"\n"+"STAFF MEMBER: "+staffEmail+"\n"+"\n"+"ASSIGNMENT: "+iCanStatement;
        var staffBody = "NOTICE: This is an automated message confirming that you have assigned a student to the HOMEWORK LIST"+"\n"+"\n"+"DATE: "+date+"\n"+"\n"+"FIRST NAME: "+firstName+"\n"+"\n"+"LAST NAME: "+lastName+"\n"+"\n"+"EMAIL ADDRESS: "+studentEmail+"\n"+"\n"+"STAFF MEMBER: "+staffEmail+"\n"+"\n"+"ASSIGNMENT: "+iCanStatement;
        var fromName = "**"
     }

     // Send Emails
        MailApp.sendEmail(studentEmail, emailSubject, studentBody, {bcc:"**@**.org", name:fromName, replyTo:staffEmail});
        MailApp.sendEmail(staffEmail, emailSubject, staffBody, {name:fromName, replyTo:staffEmail});
      }
  }

  catch(e) {
   MailApp.sendEmail("**@**.org", "Error on Intervention Spreadsheet 3.0", e.message);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the point in the right direction. It keeps erroring out with cannot call method join of undefined. with your code.

Comment: yes, there is a mistake there. change `if (!values[row].join("")) continue;`
 to  `if (!row.join("")) continue;`